# Не исполняются sql запросы в node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js

При попытке зайти на страницу, где есть sql запросы в nоde.js, в консоли выводится предупреждение:
`(node:29843) [DEP0096] DeprecationWarning: timers.unenroll() is deprecated. Please use clearTimeout instead.`
И sql запрос в итоге не исполняется.
Никаких модулей типа `timers` я не устанавливал.
Аргумент `err` в функции запроса возвращает `PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST`

Кусочек кода

`

```
app.get("/news", function(req, res) {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    c.query("SELECT `id`, `title`, `time`, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(`text`, 1, 300), '...') AS `text` FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC", function(err, result) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({
            success: true,
            err: err,
            data: result
        }));
    });
});
```

`

Модули, которые я подключаю
`

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mysql = require("mysql");
const needle = require('needle');
const fs = require("fs");
const md5 = require("md5");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
```

`

Буду очень благодарен за все!

Comment: Это же ворнинг, а не ошибка. Ваши запросы не из-за этого не исполняются. Покажите код подключения к mysql.